# Django 3 Pass Get The Selected Value Dropdown select option

Tags: python, django

Django dropdown option selected. Get data in template and select option. My code is.
views.py

```
def home(request):

compType = Type.objects.all()

comptype = request.GET.get('comp_type')
context = {
    'compType': compType
}

return render(request, 'compapp/dashboard.html', context)
```

search.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Type</label>
<select class="form-control select2" name="comp_type" style="width: 100%;">
  <!-- <option disabled="true" selected >Company Type</option> -->
  {% for i in compType %}
  <option value="{{ i }}" {% if request.GET.items == i %}selected{% endif %}>{{ i }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: hi, just change this part: `{% for i in compType %}
  <option value="{{ i.id }}" {% if request.GET.items == i %}selected{% endif %}>{{ i }}</option>
  {% endfor %}`

Comment: Not work. how get request

Answer (score 0):

imagine you have a form, (search form), that user filled it and submitted. you received this form and made the queryset and then you want to show a page contains the search results and, also the form has its fields  filled with selected values. So you have to pass that values to the results page too!  'request.GET.items' is not working ever.
what you should do is:
if the had a field named 'dr_select', in the views.py search function you should get that fields value via

```
 selected = get_object_or_404(Type, id==int(request.GET['dr_select']))
```

then pass 'selected' to the results page, and then in that template you can do what you want.

```
{% for item in compType %}
     <option value="{{ item.id }}" 
     {% if selected == item %}selected{% endif %}>{{ item } </option> 
      {% endfor %}
```

*note: because I used 'item.id' for 'value' in 'option' tag, so in backend I have to filter the Model by id too.